# Oracle Apex - There is a problem with environment! the for version 21.1.0 loaded, but 21.2.2 is expected

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I was trying to upgrade apex from 21.1.0 to 21.2.3 with patch(33420059). After successful upgrade login throughs an error "There is a problem with environment! the for version 21.1.0 loaded, but 21.2.2 is expected".

I configured the server in TOMCAT 9 with ORDS 21x, and also copied images frolder from the .zip file to folder ords\images and tomcat \i.

tried all possible advices in the google.

Regards,

Jojo

Answer (score 0):

Take in mind that APEX 21.2 static resources are available on a CDN.

> For APEX product version 21.2.2 and 21.2.3, use
> https://static.oracle.com/cdn/apex/21.2.2/. The CDN contains the
> production APEX 21.2 static resources and the updated static resources
> included in PATCH_VERSION 1, 2 and 3. Please refer to the included
> README for instructions on using the new CDN.

If you're sure about the CDN configuration, please follow these steps:

1- Run the script: `apex_rest_config.sql`
Learn more: [Configuring RESTful Services](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmig/downloading-installing-apex.html#GUID-93638EC4-5278-421B-9C19-BB68F9B31C40)

2- [Validating the Oracle REST Data Services Installation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmig/configuring-ords.html#GUID-C070563B-2080-4DB1-A5FB-48B4D1B57D77)

```
java -jar ords.war validate [--database <dbname>]
```

3- Clear the cache browser

Comment: Thank you Monica for your reply, I have tried with CDN content and the message disappears but the thing is the server will not have internet connection once the application is up. and existing applications are throwing HTML errors while running

Answer (score 0):

You have not updated /i/ (images) from older version, now you have new apex and static images from old apex - you need to replace static images location on your tomcat with new images from apex upgrade package. Make copy first of course.

Comment: I deployed new images from apex_21.2 zip folder in tomcat /i/ .. and restarted the server

Comment: So, is it working ? Also you need reverse changes made for CDN if you want host resources locally.

Comment: No it is not working 21.2

Comment: you need to provide little more information - do you have errors, or is it same error?

Comment: same error ... tried even restarting

Comment: Do you have multiple places where images are placed ?
Do you copied images to multiple places ?
Maybe /i/ points to different location than you think ?
You can try to search files across folders on server to be sure you are using right location, also be sure that ords folder after upgrade points to same location as you think (in case of ords upgrade). This instruction gave me successful upgrade today:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmig/upgrading-to-latest-apex-release.html#GUID-4B4A2BDC-11AA-4ACF-88B2-E320D6361596

Comment: I copied every where .. even removed all images and /i/ folder and recopied.

Comment: Where exactly points your /i/ ?
Can you revert your upgrade to previous version succesfully to process it once again ?

Comment: Configured ORDS on TOMCAT server, copied the images forder to ORDS directory and $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/i/

Comment: I'm afraid you have pointed your images to different place or it is still CDN.
Try to rename image folders you have copied for new versions one by one.
Then restart tomcat and clear cache in your browser and try to open your apex admin page.
When apex will show page with warning about lack of image files this is your folder.
You need to clean it and copy proper version images.
If after renaming folders for images they still appear with warning about version that's sign they are in different place you are thinking.
Then you can try to use utilities\reset_image_prefix.sql to reset prefix